# Why is Xcode's Search Navigator searching the wrong project's files?

Tags: xcode, search, project, navigator

I have a large Xcode project for a game I'm building.  I recently switched versions of the animation framework I'm using (cocos2d), and to keep things clean, I went ahead and created a brand new Xcode project from scratch.

Afer creating the new project file, I made copies of all my source files in the filesystem, then symlinked them into the new project by dragging them into the Xcode Project Navigator.  Everything worked fine.

But here's where it gets weird.  Whenever I use the Xcode Search Navigator to do global text searches on my project, it searches files from the *old* project!  And *only* files from the old project!

The only conceivable explanation I can come up with is that Xcode is somehow recognizing my filenames as being the same as were used in the old project, and has decided to ignore the newer versions in favor of the old ones.  Is there any such cache or preference within Xcode that can do such a thing?  Keep in mind the *paths* are different, since the new project's files all exist in a brand new directory.  But the class names are the same.

In case this is relevant:  I once created an Xcode Workspace that included the old version of this project (but not the new one.)  I abandoned the workspace long ago as it was problematic, in favor of working with the project directly.

**UPDATE:** This appears to be an Xcode-related problem-- I have discovered I have the same lack of search-ability in all of my projects.  I uninstalled Xcode (I had the version that was still using the Developer directory) and installed the latest version (4.3.3) that does not use the developer directory, but I am still seeing this problem.

I am curious if anyone knows a way to wipe out Xcode's cache of project code indexes, if such a thing exists, that might potentially "reset" its knowledge of my projects and thus fix the situation.  Possibly something in the Library directory?

One last clue as to what might be happening:  In addition to the search navigator failures, I noticed one of my projects was still using resources that no longer existed in the filesystem-- again, making me think Xcode has cached information about my projects somewhere and is now using outdated versions of my files that no longer exist.  [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714372/how-to-empty-caches-and-clean-all-targets-xcode-4) helped me solve that problem by resetting the simulator's content and settings, but the search issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your Find Options?  This same problem was biting me and then I remembered I had added a custom Scope in 'My Scope' that directed XCode to my other project.  Changing this back to 'Workspace' fixed the problem.